# Answering question: Spam or not?

Tags: discussion

I am not sure, is this spam?

https://security.stackexchange.com/a/46429/5518

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case the poster has described the product's features, and disclosed his affiliation, so typically we would not class this as spam.

If it was just a link to their site, or the disclosure was not there, the post would probably be deleted as spam.